# disable href on content page from Master page in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, master-pages

Just as the title says. I have code that disables all controls that runat=server. Its as follows

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In pc
   If c.HasControls Then DisableAllControls(c.Controls)

   If c.GetType.ToString.ToLower.IndexOf("webcontrols.dropdownlist") > -1 Then
      DirectCast(c, DropDownList).Enabled = False
   ElseIf c.GetType.ToString.ToLower.IndexOf("webcontrols.textbox") > -1 Then
      DirectCast(c, TextBox).Enabled = False
   ElseIf c.GetType.ToString.ToLower.IndexOf("webcontrols.radiobuttonlist") > -1 Then
      DirectCast(c, RadioButtonList).Enabled = False
   ElseIf c.GetType.ToString.ToLower.IndexOf("webcontrols.radiobutton") > -1 Then
      DirectCast(c, RadioButton).Enabled = False
   ElseIf c.GetType.ToString.ToLower.IndexOf("webcontrols.button") > -1 Then
      DirectCast(c, Button).Enabled = False
   End If
 Next
```

But I have a couple of href's in there that i want to disable also. I know they dont runat server, so how can i catch these?

Comment: sorry for not formatting. I'm not sure how to format code here.

Comment: With this I will have to get name of every href on my side and disable it. makes no sense. if you read my code i disable all buttons, ddl's txtboxes. I need to do same for <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can add `runat="server"`:

```
<a runat="server" href="..." ></a>
```

It is the only way to maintain controls using server side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add runat="server" to HTML controls too. Without it you won't be able to access the control on the server side and you won't be able to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks invalid (`If c.HasControls Then DisableAllControls(c.Controls)` has no matching `End If`) but perhaps VB.NET has added inline `If` syntax like that without me realising.

Anyway, as far as disabling all `runat="server"` controls, you should be able to just do this:

```
For Each c as WebControl In pc.OfType(Of WebControl)()
    ' Put your recursive call here as before 
    c.Enabled = False
Next
```

Now, to "disable" those other elements, you can either add `runat="server"` to them (perhaps not even possible if you have generated HTML), or you can use some JavaScript. I'm going to assume by disable you mean hide in the case of `<a>` tags?

jQuery makes this easy, with a sample script being something like:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  $('a').hide();
});
```

or:

```
/* hides all a tags under an element with class="someClass" */
$(document).load(function() {
  $('.someClass a').hide(); 
});
```

You could then have your code render this script, using something like this in your Page:

```
Dim script as String = "" /* your javascript here */
Me.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "HideTagsScript", script)
```